# Flutter page state isnt refreshing when coming back

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 pages on the first page I am calling data from an API. And on the second page, I am editing the data. But the issue is when the edit is done and I am pop bak to the first-page data is not updating in the widget. So I have to use the Nav.pop(context, true) method but it's not working.

My first page code

```
class _AddressPageState extends State<AddressPage> {
  var address = {'Address': []};
  bool showAddress = false;
  int dateindex = 0;
  var addressSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      getAddress();
    });
  }

  getAddress() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

    String _userEmail = await storage.read(key: "_userEmail");
    String _userPassword = await storage.read(key: "_userPassword");
    String url =
        'http://retailapi.airtechsolutions.pk/api/customer/login/${_userEmail}/${_userPassword}';

    print(url);
    http.Response res = await http.get(
      url,
    );
    var data = json.decode(res.body.toString());
    print(data);

    if (data['description'].toString() == "Success") {
      print(data['customer']['Addresses']);
      address['Address'].addAll(data['customer']['Addresses']);

      print(address);

      setState(() {

        showAddress = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(context),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            showAddress
                ? Flexible(
                    flex: 9,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                          Text(
                            'order.shippingaddress',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                          ).tr(),
                          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                          ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: address['Address'].length,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return SideInAnimation(
                                index,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  // onTap: widget.onPressed,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      dateindex = index;
                                      addressSelected =
                                          address['Address'][index];
                                      print(addressSelected);
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: dateindex == index
                                            ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                                            : Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                        width: dateindex == index ? 2.0 : 1.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                            showAddress
                                                ? address['Address'][index]
                                                    ['Address']
                                                : '...',
                                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textTheme
                                                .headline4),
                                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                        Text(
                                            showAddress
                                                ? address['Address'][index]
                                                    ['Address']
                                                : '...',
                                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textTheme
                                                .subtitle1),
                                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                        Text(
                                            showAddress
                                                ? address['Address'][index]
                                                    ['Address']
                                                : '...',
                                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textTheme
                                                .subtitle1),
                                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            SizedBox(
                                              width: 80.0,
                                              child: RaisedButtonWidget(
                                                title: 'product.edit',
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  // Get.to(EditAddressPage(address: address['Address'][index]));
                                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditAddressPage(address: address['Address'][index]))).then((value) {
                                                    if (value == true) {
                                                      setState(() {
                                                      });
                                                    }
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(width: 15.0),
                                            IconButton(
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                // showDeleteConfirmation(context);
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(),
            buildConfirmAddressButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On the second page, I am coming back like this `Navigator.pop(context,true);` But the page state isn't changing or refresh. What I need to is when I come back I can see the edit changes so it means my API will run again so it is not running that's why it is not updating the state also. I am stuck at this point is it not possible to refresh state or what? -_-

Comment: Would you consider pop the new data back to first page?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```dart
Navigator.push(context, secondScreen).then((result) => setState(() {}));
```

When you navigate from one screen to another, it is possible add callback to `pop` and refresh previous screen.